# Why does "int *find(const vector<int> &vec, int value)" gives me a invalid conversion error?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constants

I am new to C++ and trying to play with some examples in book "Essential C++". When I write this code from the book:

```
int *find(const vector<int> &vec, int value) { ... }
```

The g++ compiler gives me an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int *' [-fpermissive]
```

I try to change it to

```
const int *find(const vector<int> &vec, int value)
```

and it works fine.

So I am just wondering is there any detail reason for this? Thanks!

Here is the code from the book:

```
int* find(const vector<int> &vec, int value) {
    for(int ix = 0; ix < vec.size(); ++ix)
    {
        if(vec[ix] == value) 
        return &vec[ix];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you are returning...

Comment: It appears you are returning a value that is const. Can you post the body of the function?

Comment: Just use `std::find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are doing something like

```
int *find(const vector<int> &vec, int value) 
{ 
  ... 
  return &vec[someIndex];
}
```

You cannot do that, since you are passing a `const` reference to the vector. Hence the need to return `const int*`.

What you really should do it use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
vector<int>::const_iterator i = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);

// check if an element was found and print it out
if (i != vec.end()) std::cout << *i << std::endl;
```

This has the added advantage that it does not produce undefined behaviour when a value is not found in the vector.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did in the code. So does this mean the compiler checks if the code is returning an address from a const container?

Comment: @zhxb515 correct, the compiler can check the constness, and what you have is an error. Your function is also not guaranteed to return. This is the undefined behaviour I was referring to. The compiler can give you a warning about this.

Comment: Oh, yes. I forget to type "return 0;". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value that `find()` is returning is `const`, but your function definition specifies that the return type is not `const`.

You cannot change a non-`const` variable to be `const`.

A `const int*` is a pointer to an unchangeable `int`. Since the function returns an `int*`, code that handles the return value of that function would be able to change the value of the integer that is pointed to. If you try to return something that is of type `const int*`, then this would allow you to change an integer that is unchangeable - hence the complaint from the compiler.